# how to resolve compile error CS0234 from Google Calendar API for .NET

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, google-calendar-api

I'm creating a console app in C# using VS2012 that should interact with Google's Calendar API. Following the online instructions, I've attempted to retrieve the .NET version of this API through NuGet with this command:

Install-Package Google.Apis.Calendar.v3

After having successfully installed this package, and adding some code copied from the .NET portion of this page

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/instantiate

I attempted to compile. But, the compile attempt failed with these errors:

1>E:\tools\daxtell\PunchCardOps\GoogleCalendarApiOps\GoogleCalendarSvc.cs(1,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Auth' does not exist in the namespace 'Google.Apis' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
1>E:\tools\daxtell\PunchCardOps\GoogleCalendarApiOps\GoogleCalendarSvc.cs(3,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Services' does not exist in the namespace 'Google.Apis' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

What can I do to resolve these errors?

Answer (score 0):

There are two dependencies for the calendar nuget package (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Calendar.v3):

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis/

and https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Auth/

Comment: Thank you so much for responding! Should I fetch Google.Apis and Google.Apis.Auth from NuGet separately and explicitly? Why wouldn't NuGet recursively retrieve all necessary dependencies for Google.Apis.Calendar.v3 when I perform Install-Package upon it?

Comment: Yes, request them separately and explicitly.